# $.get in jquery not executing while on html page through javascript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get, overwrite

I've been trying to create a simple download counter for my site, in the following way: To use jquery to retrieve the value of a txt which indicates download times, then to use jquery to call ajax to execute a PHP file, which would in turn overwrite such txt file (incrementing it on the php file) then store it, then reading back the value with jquery.  Before I forget, and to avoid any misinformation, here is the whole HTML code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>GreenDream: SMS Sender</title>
    <link rel=StyleSheet type="text/css" href="http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/CSS/greendream.css" />
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/images/dreamicon.ico">  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/JS/greendream.js"></script>
  </head>
<body onload="startTime(); handleTextFile()">
  <div id="background">
    <img src="http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/images/greentwi.png" class="stretch" alt="" />
  </div>

  <br />

  <table align="center">

    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/"><img src="http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/images/dream.png" align="middle"></a>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div id='pbutton' style="width:113px; height:41px; margin:0px;white-space:nowrap; word-spacing:0;"><a class="button" href="http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/programs.html">Programs</a></div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div id='gbutton' style="width:93px; height: 41px; margin:0px;white-space:nowrap; word-spacing:0;"><a class="button" href="http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/games.html">Games</a></div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div id='tbutton' style="width:108px; height: 41px; margin:0px;white-space:nowrap; word-spacing:0;"><a class="button" href="http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/tutorials.html">Tutorials</a></div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div id='bbutton' style="width:74px; height: 41px; margin:0px;white-space:nowrap; word-spacing:0;"><a class="button" href="http://blog.gfcf14greendream.com/">Blog</a></div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div id='mbutton' style="width:114px; height: 41px; margin:0px;white-space:nowrap; word-spacing:0;"><a class="button" href="http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/aboutme.html">About Me</a></div>                        
        </td>

        <td style="padding-left:50px">
            <div id='daytitle'></div>
            <div id='clock'></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

  <br />

  <div style="text-align: center; color:#00FF00; font-size: 20px">The following is a Visual C++ program that was designed specifically to send text messages to a phone... Free of charge!!</div>
  <br />
  <div style="text-align: center; color:#FFFF00; font-size: 20px">THE GOOD: If you have a prepaid phone, then you can send text messages to a phone without wasting your minutes...</div>
  <br />
  <div style="text-align: center; color:#FF8000; font-size: 20px">THE BAD : Since I haven't been able to put a Skype or Google Voice library for use with C++, this application depends on using what's known as an SMS gateway, different for every phone carrier... meaning you must know your recipient's carrier to be able to send a message!</div>
  <br />
  <div style="text-align: center; color:#FF0000; font-size: 20px">THE UGLY: This program doesn't work on computers connected to safe networks (such as college/university networks) ... at least not yet!</div>
  <br />
  <div style="text-align: center; color:#00FF00; font-size: 20px">You will probably need the Visual C++ Redistributable Package (or the .NET framework or both, but most likely just the package) to run this program, if you don't have it installed on your pc yet</div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div style="text-align: center; color:#0000C8; font-size: 20px">Click <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555">here</a> to download the Visual C++ Redistributable Package</div>
  <div style="text-align: center; color:#0000C8; font-size: 20px">Click <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851">here</a> to download the .NET Framework 4</div>
  <br />
  <br />

  <div style="text-align: center; color:#00FF00; font-size: 20px"><a class="button" id="downbutton" style="width:115px;margin:0px;white-space:nowrap; word-spacing:0;" href="http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/Programs/SMSSender/SMS Sender.exe">Click here to download SMS Sender</a></div>
  <br />
  <div id='counter' style="text-align: center;"></div>

  <br />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function handleTextFile()
    {
        document.getElementById('counter').style.color = "rgb(0, 255, 0)";
        document.getElementById('counter').style.fontWeight = 'bold';

        var downcounter = 0;

        $.get("http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/counters/smssender.txt", function(data){
            downcounter = data;
            if (downcounter == 1)   $("#counter").text("SMS Sender has been downloaded " + downcounter + " time...");   
            else $("#counter").text("SMS Sender has been downloaded " + downcounter + " times..."); 
        });

        $("#downbutton").click( function(){     

            $.get("http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/PHP/smssender.php", function(data){
                $.get("http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/counters/smssender.txt", function(data){
                    downcounter = data;
                    if (downcounter == 1)   $("#counter").text("SMS Sender has been downloaded " + downcounter + " time...");   
                    else $("#counter").text("SMS Sender has been downloaded " + downcounter + " times..."); 
                });             
            });
        });

    }

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Upon running the page, I use this code (a piece from above) to read a txt file and get download count (this works):

```
var downcounter = 0;

        $.get("http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/counters/smssender.txt", function(data){
            downcounter = data;
            if (downcounter == 1)   $("#counter").text("SMS Sender has been downloaded " + downcounter + " time...");   
            else $("#counter").text("SMS Sender has been downloaded " + downcounter + " times..."); 
        });
```

Then when the downbutton variable is clicked, this code should execute:

```
$("#downbutton").click( function(){     

            $.get("http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/PHP/smssender.php", function(data){
                $.get("http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/counters/smssender.txt", function(data){
                    downcounter = data;
                    if (downcounter == 1)   $("#counter").text("SMS Sender has been downloaded " + downcounter + " time...");   
                    else $("#counter").text("SMS Sender has been downloaded " + downcounter + " times..."); 
                });             
            });
        });
```

, which should read a php file, whose code is:

```
<?php
    $counter = intval(file_get_contents('/homepages/37/d434704165/htdocs/counters/smssender.txt'));
    $counter++; 
    file_put_contents('/homepages/37/d434704165/htdocs/counters/smssender.txt', $counter);
?>
```

And running the php would overwrite the txt file "smssender" and thus increase the number of downloads. I noticed that manually entering the address of the php file on my site actually works, and the download increment takes place. Yet when JQuery executes the code, no increment takes place. I'm guessing it's on this line, but what would be the error here? :

```
$.get("http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/counters/smssender.txt", function(data){
```

Thank you very much for any help or suggestion!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be a lot simpler to just use the PHP page by itself. You can use GET variables to determine whether you need to increment the download counter. For instance, do something like this in your PHP file:

```
<?php
$total = (int)file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/counters/smssender.txt');

if (isset($_GET['i'])) {
    $total++; 
    // now update the file for future use
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/counters/smssender.txt', $total);
}

echo $total;
?>
```

Then you can call the PHP page by itself in the ajax so that you don't have to worry about both calls being executed simultaneously and causing errors. You could now just make a call to "smssender.php" when you want to retrieve the current number of downloads. In addition, you could call "smssender.php?i" when you want to retrieve the current number of downloads and increment the file contents.

If you wanted to only increment the file's contents and not echo the output, you could add another if statement, but I don't know if that's what you're trying to do. If so, please let me know and I can show you code for that as well. I hope that helps, if not, just let me know.

UPDATE: Just change your code to this:

Javascript File:

```
$.get("/PHP/smssender.php", function(data) {
    $("#counter").text(data);            
});

$("#downbutton").click( function() {     
    $.get("/PHP/smssender.php?i", function(data) {
        $("#counter").text(data);            
    });
});
```

PHP File:

```
<?php
$total = (int)file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/counters/smssender.txt');

if (isset($_GET['i'])) {
    $total++; 
    // now update the file for future use
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/counters/smssender.txt', $total);
}

$suffix = ($total == 1) ? 'time' : 'times';

echo 'SMS Sender has been downloaded ' . $total . ' ' . $suffix . '...';
?>
```

Now, you can simplify your Javascript/jQuery by A LOT. This code will have the exact same behavior as the code you had, without any errors. Now, I will explain the changes I have made. First, you only have to call a single PHP file with the $.get() method, regardless if you are just retrieving the current number of downloads or whether you are incrementing the total.

Secondly, the text handling is done in the PHP file. You no longer determine if it has been downloaded 1 or more times in Javascript, instead the PHP file handles this because it's a lot faster than retrieving the data and making a calculation afterwards.

Lastly, I made the download button only call $.get() once so that you don't have to worry about errors resulting from an attempt to retrieve two different pages simultaneously. Try replacing your code with the new code I posted above and let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand (sorry but this file writing is my first attempt at using php). Do you mean to try to combine all my $.get() into using something like `$.ajax()` to call the php page?

Comment: I updated my code. Please just use the code I posted after "UPDATE".

Comment: Thank you for the code. I hate to be a bother, but while the first $.get works, the second one (the one where php has ?i) doesn't. I wrote an `alert("downloaded");` before the `$.get(...php?i")` line and it never appeared, so the error is still at the $get to overwrite: `$.get("/PHP/smssender.php?i", function(data) {` But I don't get an error while manually going either to php or php?i

Comment: Have you checked the Javascript Console to see if it is returning any errors? Try changing smssender.php?i to smssender.php?i=1 and see if that fixes the glitch, because I'm not sure if jQuery allows loading a URL with undefined variables, even if the explicit values aren't needed in the page. Also, try recopying and pasting the code to make sure you aren't missing a piece of syntax, such as a }.

Comment: I've noticed the file writing works only once, in internet explorer and the android browser. But not on firefox or chrome. Yet checking the console, I did notice some CSS bugs. Would that stop the overwrite somehow? If you wish to see the page, it is http://www.gfcf14greendream.com/smssender.html

Comment: Why aren't you putting your Javascript in the head tag of your page?

Comment: I guess because that's the way I saw it on a tutorial. I changed it, yet it's still the same

Comment: You haven't even attached an onclick event to the link. Where is the handleTextFile() function being called other than in the body's onload event? Or is it ever getting called again?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've now changed the code to include an onclick keyword inside the div tag which is the download button, and made a separate function to overwrite. It now works on firefox, and while at first it looked like it couldn't work on chrome, it was the cache files that didn't allow me to see the overwrite. Thank you so very much!!

Comment: No problem, please up-vote and accept my answer since it helped you fix your problem. The more you accept answers to the questions you ask, the more likely people are going to help you in the future. People like to get credit for their help. :)

Comment: I would, and I wanted to do the same with the answer of another person on a previous question, but I haven't reached 15 rep yet, so I will as soon as I do

Comment: I just up-voted your question so check again, you should have enough reputation.

Comment: just got it, so there you go!